# Retrieving the key name on AVMetadataItem for an AVAsset in iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios, video

I am trying to identify the different metadata items on a video on the iPad. So far I was able to successfully use the AVAsset libraries to find the file, and generate an array of AVMetadataItems using `metadataForFormat:`. Only iTunes and Quicktime User data formats were found in the file. The issue is now that I have that information, I have no way of identifying what is what. I intended to load a dictionary with the information, indexed by the metadata key, but using the `key` property of AVMetadataItem appears not to work correctly as if returns a number (debugger says its an NSCFNumber). Here is some sample code of what I am doing:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [[valAsset defaultRepresentation] retain];
NSURL *url = [representation url];
AVURLAsset *aAsset = [[AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil] retain];
metaDataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] retain];
NSArray *fmtmetadata = [aAsset metadataForFormat:@"com.apple.itunes"];
for (AVMetadataItem* meta in fmtmetadata)
{
    [metaDataDict setObject:[meta stringValue]
             forKey:[meta key]];
    NSLog(@"metadata: key = %@", [meta key]);
}
```

This yields the following output in the debugger console:

```
metadata: key = -1452383891
metadata: key = -1452841618
metadata: key = 1684370275
metadata: key = 1818518899
metadata: key = 1937009003
metadata: key = -1453101708
```

Incidentally, changing the NSLog line to read:

```
NSLog(@"metadata: %@", meta);
```

gives us output like:

```
metadata: keySpace=itsk, key=desc, commonKey=(null), locale=(null), value=This is the Description of the Video, time={INVALID}, duration={INVALID}, extras={
    dataType = 1;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like these keys are encoded ID3 tags:

1684370275 = 0x64657363 = {'d', 'e', 's', 'c'}

1818518899 = 0x6C646573 = {'l', 'd', 'e', 's'}

1937009003 = 0x7374696B = {'s', 't', 'i', 'k'}

etc.

Comment: GREAT, thanks for the answer, I had a hunch about that... any idea if there's a method to decode them?

Comment: Hmm.. this is untested but I think something like

`NSInteger key = [meta key];`
`NSString *keyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4s", &key]`

should work.

Comment: Thanks... Here's what I ended up doing:
NSUInteger akey = NSSwapInt([(NSNumber *)[meta key] unsignedIntegerValue]);
NSString *keyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4s",&akey];

Answer (score 1):

You can use following extensions:

```swift
extension AVMetadataItem {
    var keyString: String {
        if key is NSString { return key as! String}
        else if key is NSNumber {

            var keyValue = (key as? NSNumber)?.uint32Value ?? 0 
            keyValue = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(keyValue) 
            
            let array = withUnsafeBytes(of: &keyValue) { Array($0) }

            let string = String(decoding: array, as: UTF8.self)
            return String(string.map {$0 == "�" ? "@" : $0 })
        } else {
            return "Unknown"
        }
    }
}
```

It can return strings like this:

| keyString | Description |
| --- | --- |
| @alb | Album |
| aART | Album Artist |
| @ART | Artist |
| @gen | Gener |
| @nam | Title |
| @cmt | Comment |

To use:

```swift
let albumMetaData: [AVMetadataItem] = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: asset.metadata, filteredByIdentifier: .iTunesMetadataAlbum)

print(albumMetaData.first?.keyString) // @alb
```

Credit goes to:
Learning AV Foundation: A Hands-on Guide to Mastering the AVFoundation Framework (McCune, Bob)